# How to incorporate an existing library of python functions into libreoffice calc so they can be used like user written BASIC function in cells

Tags: python, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I'm a noob at using macros but have written a couple of user function in BASIC that I can use just like functions in LO Calc cells. I was looking to write more but found that a Caleb Bell has has already written a great series of Engineering function libraries in python, one of which is fluids 0.1.88
I'm not familiar with python and new to user macros/function but from what I can tell within python these functions are called as fluids.function_name(variables).
I understand in LO Calc user functions can be written in Python so would like to know if there is a way to import existing python libraries into Calc so they can be called by their python function name and used within cells?

Thanks,
Mark.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way is to create a Calc add-in that includes the Python functions. This is a powerful solution but difficult for people new to LibreOffice programming.

Alternatively, write a Basic user-defined function with glue code to call Python. This too is more difficult than writing a simple Basic UDF.

For more information:

- my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50785510/define-a-libreoffice-calc-custom-function-in-python
- a similar question with an answer at https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/10219/writing-user-defined-functions-in-python/
- google "libreoffice python user defined function"